# Print dynamic images along with text

Tags: xamarin.forms, zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I need to print dynamic images through a `Zebra-ZD420` printer along with text. I am printing the text using `ZPL`.

To print the static images I upload the image on `http://labelary.com` and get the `ASCII` for image along with text.

Can someone help me with printing the dynamic images , I understand the image has to be converted into `ASCII` before sending it as `ZPL` command.

I am using `LinkOS` SDK to print from a `Xamarin.Forms` app on bluetooth from `iOS` device.

Comment: I've never done it before, but you will have to convert to base64 and send that within the ZPL.  From the research I did a while back, its quite complex.

Comment: Well I got the answer and its pretty easy please reach out if anyone needs this !

Comment: Can you post the answer to your own question?

Comment: Firstly you have to save the image to the printer.
    printer.StoreImage("R:IMAGE.GRF", Picture.Path, 400, 300);

And print the same image using ZPL ,"^XA^FO320,720^XGR:IMAGE.GRF^FS".

You can add more ZPL commands along with following command !

Comment: Ashish, can you put this as the answer, not a comment on the question?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution for this.

You have to save the image to the printer, `printer.StoreImage("R:IMAGE.GRF", Picture.Path, 400, 300)`and print the same image using ZPL ,`"^XA^FO320,720^XGR:IMAGE.GRF^FS"`. You can add more ZPL commands along with following command !